# Button is moving a little bit when i hover it

Tags: html, css

I just leanred CSS and try to doing some tutorials.

I have a button with this CSS

```
.btn {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-sign-up {
    font-size: 14px;
    border-color: rgba(238, 67, 116, 1);
}
```

I just want button just change the color, and remove the border while i hover it.

But the result is just like this:
[image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkwEP.gif)

I've googled it, but got stuck because the result i got just another tutorial how to make my button move, not to make it doesn't move.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance!

Edit: After i try to make another button, this is because of `border: none;` that makes my button move slightly. Is it any other way to make border away but the button doesn't move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because you are removing the border. Instead of removing it, make it the same color as the background.

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button:hover {
  background: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Or, if you want the border to really disappear, use `transparent`:

```css
.button:hover {
  background: red;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see below code, on `.btn:hover` you can write your css

```
.btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```css
.btn {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}


.btn-sign-up {
    font-size: 14px;
    border-color: rgba(238, 67, 116, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">one</div>
<div class="btn">two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue before,

The reason why the section moves a little when you hover on the button is because the button is probably using a relative positioning. This means that the button is positioned relative to its parent element, and when you hover on it, the browser moves the parent element up or down to make room for the button's hover effect.

To fix this, you can use absolute positioning for the button. This will position the button relative to the viewport, so it will not move the parent element when you hover on it.

Here is an example of how to use absolute positioning to fix this issue:

```
.button {
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
}
```